# POST joson data using HttpUrlConnection

Tags: java, android, json, post, httpurlconnection

I have this JSON data which I want to post using httpurl connection.

```
POST http://example.com/2_1/payment/tel%3A%2B919825010000/transactions/amount HTTP/1.1 
Accept: application/json 
Content-Type: application/json 
X-Forwarded-For: 129.78.138.66, 129.78.64.103 
Authorization: Basic<base64 encoded application credentials> 
{
"amountTransaction":
     { 
        "clientCorrelator": "54321", 
        "endUserId": "tel:+919825010000", 
        "paymentAmount": 
         { 
             "chargingInformation": 
              { 
                  "code": "WGAME_0010_Ind00001111", 
                  "description": ["Alien Invaders Game"] 
              }, 
             "chargingMetaData" : 
              { 
                  "onBehalfOf" : "Example Games Inc", 
                  "purchaseCategoryCode" : "Game", 
                  "channel" : "SMS", 
                  "taxAmount" : 0 
              } 
         }, 
        "referenceCode": "REF-12345", 
        "transactionOperationStatus": "Charged"  
         }   
    }
}
```

How can I make POST request of all these data using Httpurlconnection.?

Comment: Are you adding the JSON object as a header field?

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you can start with:

```
httpClient = createHttpClient();

//You wanna use POST method.
mPost = new HttpPost(_urlStr);

//Head
mPost.addHeader(new BasicHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"));

//Body
((HttpPost) mPost).setEntity(new StringEntity(jsonText));

//Do it.
client.execute(mPost);
```

You can also check out [this tutorial](https://github.com/stefanklumpp/Simple-HTTP-Client/tree/master/src/com/devstream/http) or [this tutorial](http://hmkcode.com/android-send-json-data-to-server/) for more help.